# LINQ to Entities result not being sorted right

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ to Entities query that is supposed to output data based on a `DateTime` field in Ascending order. But, it is not outputting the data in any particular order and I can't figure out the reason.

I have done a basic `SELECT` statement to the DB and get the data back in the proper order. It appears that the `OrderBy` command of the LINQ query is just being ignored. How can I see SQL being generated?

I have tried LINQPad but it keeps giving a BS error about context not being updated even though an `UPDATE-DATABASE` command says no pending changes Or if I can not see what is being generated what is the best way to be debugging this?

```
db.Releases
.Where(r => r.SectionID == model.ID)
.Include("Platform")
.Include("Region")
.Include("Publisher")
.OrderBy(r => r.DateReleased.HasValue)
.Select(r => new ReleaseInfoVM()
{
    ReleaseName = r.Name,
    Platform = r.Platform.Name,
    Publisher =r.Publisher.Name,
    Region = r.Region.Name,
    ISBN = r.ISBN,
    DateReleased = r.DateReleased,
    EstimatedReleaseDate = r.EstimatedReleaseDate
}).ToList();
```

Comment: [IntelliTrace is useful](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=intellitrace+2013), if having a compatible VS. It won't show the bound values but it will show the 'shape' of the query. Also I find it handy to connect to SQL Server Diagnostics; in addition to being able to see the actual queries (*and* values used) it helps awareness of "what" is happening; and on occasion can point out sub-par queries (or perhaps non-aggregated queries) before they even become an issue.

Comment: Did you profile/trace that query? Could be interesting how EF generate the Order by clause. With CASE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.HasValue` returns a boolean. True if the property is not null. That won't work. Instead, try:

```
.OrderBy(r => r.DateReleased)
```

As @user2864740 pointed out in the comments, to ensure that the null values go to the end of the list, try:

```
.OrderBy(r => r.DateRelease ?? DateTime.Max)
```

Comment: Some times `DateReleased` will not have a value in it, with out `.HasValue` how can I make sure those with no value will show at the end of the results?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete `r => r.DateRelease ?? DateTime.Max` should have the desired behavior in that case. (When DateRelease is null the 'maximum' value will be used instead, putting it at the end.) This will still leave the rows 'with no date releases' (or the *same* release date) unordered among themseleves, however.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try, also any other way to debug besides LINQPad? As stated in my post it is not working with my context. It says it is out of date when VS says it is not.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked your mention of LINQPad... unfortunately I don't know of another option.